# the right tool and the right way to measure network throughput

Tags: networking, performance, speed, iperf3

I am confused with different results of different tools

here is what speed-test.net tells

```bash
 London, UK       87.48 ms    0.0%    404.94 Mbps    931.82 Mbps    M247 Ltd - London 
 Manchester, UK   114.50 ms   N/A     58.52 Mbps     553.54 Mbps    Vodafone UK - Manchester 
 Dublin, IE       98.51 ms    0.0%    2486.52 Mbps   808.76 Mbps    Three Ireland - Dublin 
 Amsterdam, NL    80.01 ms    0.0%    342.86 Mbps    967.25 Mbps    Melbicom - Amsterdam 
 Eygelshoen, NL   88.88 ms    0.0%    698.33 Mbps    361.62 Mbps    SkyLink Data Center BV - Eygelshoven 
 Paris, FR        82.78 ms    0.0%    2680.65 Mbps   919.69 Mbps    ORANGE - Paris 
 Marseille, FR    93.89 ms    0.0%    2511.28 Mbps   785.73 Mbps    GSL Networks - Marseille 
 Madrid, ES       101.33 ms   0.0%    2425.24 Mbps   825.04 Mbps    Orange - Jazztel - Madrid 
 Barcelona, ES    121.26 ms   0.0%    652.15 Mbps    816.51 Mbps    Adamo - Barcelona 
 Lisbon, PT       113.32 ms   0.0%    665.18 Mbps    725.60 Mbps    Edgoo Networks - Lisbon
```

here is the result of `nuttcp`

```bash
nuttcp -4 -N 10 -i 1   -T10 IP-of-SERVER


    0.1875 MB /   1.00 sec =    1.5728 Mbps
    0.6250 MB /   1.00 sec =    5.2429 Mbps
    0.3750 MB /   1.00 sec =    3.1455 Mbps
    0.6250 MB /   1.00 sec =    5.2427 Mbps
    0.6250 MB /   1.00 sec =    5.2433 Mbps
    0.2500 MB /   1.00 sec =    2.0972 Mbps
    0.6250 MB /   1.00 sec =    5.2429 Mbps
    0.6250 MB /   1.00 sec =    5.2429 Mbps
    0.6250 MB /   1.00 sec =    5.2428 Mbps
    0.0000 MB /   1.00 sec =    0.0000 Mbps
    0.6250 MB /   1.00 sec =    5.2429 Mbps
    0.0000 MB /   1.00 sec =    0.0000 Mbps
    0.6250 MB /   1.00 sec =    5.2431 Mbps
    0.0000 MB /   1.00 sec =    0.0000 Mbps
    0.6250 MB /   1.00 sec =    5.2430 Mbps
    0.0000 MB /   1.00 sec =    0.0000 Mbps

    7.0724 MB /  16.47 sec =    3.6031 Mbps 0 %TX 0 %RX 88.38 msRTT
```

here is the `iperf3` output

```bash
iperf3 --client IP-of-SERVER --time 10 --parallel 1


[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec  1.34 MBytes  11.2 Mbits/sec   77    124 KBytes       
[  5]   1.00-2.00   sec   445 KBytes  3.65 Mbits/sec  120   93.3 KBytes       
[  5]   2.00-3.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec   96   90.5 KBytes       
[  5]   3.00-4.00   sec   445 KBytes  3.65 Mbits/sec   96   90.5 KBytes       
[  5]   4.00-5.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec   99   90.5 KBytes       
[  5]   5.00-6.00   sec   445 KBytes  3.65 Mbits/sec   90   79.2 KBytes       
[  5]   6.00-7.00   sec   445 KBytes  3.65 Mbits/sec   79   48.1 KBytes       
[  5]   7.00-8.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec   55   62.2 KBytes       
[  5]   8.00-9.00   sec   445 KBytes  3.65 Mbits/sec   57   62.2 KBytes       
[  5]   9.00-10.00  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec   58   62.2 KBytes       
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  3.51 MBytes  2.94 Mbits/sec  827             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.71  sec  2.79 MBytes  2.19 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

The host provider uses speed-net cli and tells their speed is fine and hos no issue

And the clients tell they are suffering low speed

who should I believe ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you re-test after `sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0`?

Comment: @u1686_grawity yes done - both `iperf3` and `nuttcp` results are the same (very low)